# conflict detection and resolution for unique field in SymmetricDS

Tags: symmetricds

I have this 2 sample data with **PK**(primary key) set to **id** and **email**,**phone** field set to **UNIQUE** field :

id: 1
email: jhon.doe@mailinator.com
phone: 123
last_modified: 14-9-2017

id: 23
email: jhon.doe@mailinator.com
phone: 678
last_modified: 23-10-2017

The question is when both data do some synchronization it will got unique field constraint violation, because of the same email data, how do symmetricds get solve this situation?

Answer (score 0):

assuming the table name is `user` insert into `sym_conflict`:

```
insert into symmetric_ds.sym_conflict(
 conflict_id,
 source_node_group_id,
 target_node_group_id,
 target_table_name,
 detect_type,
 resolve_type,
 ping_back,
 create_time,
 last_update_time
) values (
 'conflict_user',
 'replace_with_source_node_group_id',
 'replace_with_target_node_group_id',
 'user',
 'USE_CHANGED_DATA',
 'FALLBACK',
 'OFF',
 current_timestamp,
 current_timestamp
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Mr. Boris Pavlović, I have already created the conflict configuration as your explanation but it only detect for PK(primary key) and can't be used for **UNIQUE** field. If both data come from 2 client node and have internet connection problem(offline). So when the data insert locally, there's no problem, but when both client do sync to the server it will have problem because of the email data which set to **UNIQUE** have the same value. Is there any extended conflict configuration to handle this situation?

Comment: replace FALLBACK with IGNORE or NEWER_WINS

Comment: @BorisPavlović based on the documentation NEWER_WINS is only for TIMESTAMP or VERSION.